# IIS 7.5 forms authentication against Active directory not working in server (but it works on VS)

Tags: forms, active-directory, ldap, forms-authentication, iis-7.5

I'm developing a User manage using .net 4.0 (c#) to enable flags related to the users account, change names, add users and all this stuff related with A.D.

When I run the application in visual studio, in my laptop, it works fine, so I can add users, change attributes, enable flags, etc.. through ldap and using Membership but When I publish the app into the server, It doesn't works, and the ldap connection string is the same.

So through my laptop I can modify the users of the domain attributes but when published into the server I cant! I installed a Visual Studio into the server to try to debug the error and It works as well, so the error is when I publish the site into IIS.

I don't know why in IIS the same functions that works into visual sutdio IIS doesn't works..

In the javascript console browser (against server published into IIS version) I see this error:

Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Acess denied.

Any idea?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the IIS server is a part of the AD domain and that it's computer account is working correctly.  Here is a powershell command to [test the secure channel](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378948%28WS.10%29.aspx) or you can use NetDom from the cmd shell `Netdom verify iiscomputername /domain:yourdomain`.